# how can i use a Polymer element after instantiating it?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

For example

```
var todopopup = new TodoPopup(); todopopup.open();
```

will this work??

Hello world

```
</template>
<script>
TodoPopup = Polymer({
        is : 'todo-popup' ,
        behaviors : [Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new instance imperatively like

```
var todopupup = document.createElement('todo-popup');
```

See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements

You can attach it somewhere.

```
document.body.appendChild(todopupup);
todopopup.open();
```